# VB .Net WPF Binding 2 controls to dictionary

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have been trying to get my head round binding in WPF forms and am lost in this. I'm trying to do binding in VB .net code. I have the interface:

```
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and if I have a dictionary:

```
Public Property myDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

which I fill up with a key-value bunch of data, then I would like to populate a combobox on a WPF window with the key. So far using the following:

```
myCombo.ItemsSource = myDict
myCombo.DisplayMemberPath = "Key"
```

Then I'm trying to link the combobox to a textblock, so that the combobox shows the key and the textblock shows the value. There are lots of these combobox-textbox combinations, so can't really hard code this or have it in xaml. The last thing I tried which does something is the following:

```
Dim aBinding As New Binding("Value")
aBinding.Source = myDict
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, aBinding)
```

This then shows the textblock to have the first value in the dictionary, but doesn't alter with the combobox. I've tried binding the combobox in the same manner and with a new binding variable, which has the effect of blanking the combobox, but cannot seem to get this working.

Apologies if this is a really, really simple problem, but I'm very new at using binding in WPF, mainly because I've avoided it.

Comment: Why the objection to doing it in XAML?

Comment: Because i have quite a lot of them and need to create controls at run time with binding.

Comment: I apologize, I should have been more specific: In XAML with an ItemsControl and one or more templates.

Comment: Because I didn't think you could create controls with binding in xaml on the fly whilst the program is running. As mentioned, I'm a novice with wpf and binding.

Comment: Are you creating a lot of the same type of control, a bunch of different ones? The usual way to do dynamic UI in XAML is to have a collection of whatever the UI represents -- Users, used cars, hamburger toppings, whatever -- bind that to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl/ListBox/whatever, and have one DataTemplate per type of item in the list (if only one item type, that's very simple). The itemscontrol/whatever instantiates UI for each list item based on the appropriate DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the TextBlock binding like this:

```
Dim aBinding As New Binding("SelectedItem.Value")
aBinding.Source = myCombo
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, aBinding)
```

Comment: Great stuff!! Thank you - ok, yes i was referencing the object in the path. Now i see what you meant. Even though only 3 lines of code, this is brilliant!